# How to rename all files in C:\*.exe.old.exe to remove .exe.old

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a few hundred files that I need to rename from *.exe.old.exe to just *.exe and I'm looking for a batch script or FOR /r script to achieve this. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just some nested FOR commands using the command modifiers.

```
@echo off

FOR /R C:\ %%G IN (*.EXE.OLD.EXE) DO (
    FOR %%H in ("%%~nG") DO rename "%%~G" "%%~nH"
)
```